# If there are 28 teams and they all play eachother once how many games will there be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

And is there a quick formula to figure this out also?

Comment: Maybe try a smaller number (4 teams or 5 teams) instead and find a systematic way of counting the number of games. Then see if you can find a pattern to generalize to your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ["handshake problem"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HandshakeProblem.html). The general formula for this is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which is the formula for $n\choose2$: the number of ways we can choose a pair of teams from $n$ teams. The answer is $\frac{28 * 27}{2} = 378$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: read about [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First naievely: there will be $28\times 27$ games, since each of the $28$ teams plays $27$ games.

But then - realizing that every match is counted twice like this - there will be $\frac12\times28\times27$ games.